# make a background image map in css

Tags: css, image, dictionary

The background of my site's header is an image.

I am trying to get an image map on the top right hand corner of the header.

Every time I make a map it shifts when the page is resized if i use

```
    position: relative.
```

If I use any other position type it goes to the right location but the the map area becomes a tiny 0x1 box

Is there a way to make the map stay put in CSS? Any other ideas?
(from the research I've done it doesn't seem to work in HTML because the the image is a background)

---

```
                                                            |
    |-----------------------------------------------|       |
    |                           ------------------  |       |
    |              HEADER       |  put map here  |  |       |
    |                           ------------------  |       |
    |                                               |       |
    |-----------------------------------------------|       |
    |                                               |       |
    |                                               |       |
    |               Rest of Site                    |       |
    |                                               |       |
    |                                               |       |
    |                                               |       |
    |-----------------------------------------------|       |
                                                            |
                                                            |
```

Comment: Can you show us the CSS you've been using?

Comment: `#header {
 width:733px;
 height:128px;
 background:url(/images/image.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
 }
 #header .sitelink {
  padding-top:16px;
  padding-left:25px;
  }
 #header .logo {
  margin-left:36px;
  margin-top:35px;
  display:none;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your image map always positioned in the top right hand corner of your header, regardless of browser viewport width, try (something like):

```
.image-map {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 12px;
right: 12px;
width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it just seemed to make the map be 1px wide.  Could there be a reason for that?